# I am getting x is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, error-handling

I wrote a simple programe where wrote a  java script function as given below

```js
function add( num1,num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}


module.export={
    add
}

console.log (add(5,4));
```

given below is another function index.spec.js which is importing add function from index.js

```js
const assert = require('assert')
const { add } = require('./index')


console.log(add(5,6))
```

So when I try to run the index.spec.js using npm commmand , I get the error "add is not afunction" as shown below
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojGhc.png)

Comment: How you are running this logic? in web?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: try module.exports

Answer (score 4):

you're exporting the module in the wrong way, change it to

```
module.exports = { add }; //with the final s
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks karim, I was stuck with this for past two hours